# Transfer time at BKK airport

Tags: transit, bkk

Are 2 hours enough to transfer from domestic to international at BKK (Suvarnabhumi Airport, Bangkok, Thailand)?

About 8am, weekday, with 1 checked luggage.

Comment: As not everybody knows all the airport codes can you please edit in the country and airport for BKK, and please also add the airport you arrive from and leave to as well as the airline(s) involved and whether you are on one ticket or are self connecting.

Comment: As usual: in the same ticket, if the airline sold it, they think it’s doable, and they generally have to take care of you if you miss your connection. On separate tickets, probably doable but with very little margin to spare, and if you miss the check-in/bag drop deadline you are on your own: ticket most likely cancelled (possibly Including return flight), have to rebook and pay for a new ticket at last minute prices… I definitely wouldn’t do it u less the second flight is frequent and cheap (even at the last minute).

Comment: Adding details of the airlines/flights involved may yield a more detailed answer.